# Implementing Apple push notification service to iphone with java

Tags: java, iphone

I have to develop a service which sends push notifications to iPhone using java. Just wanted to know what is the best way to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962326/how-to-send-push-notification-message-to-iphone-using-java

this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [java-apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns)

Answer (score 0):

[Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) is pretty easy to setup. They have really nice debugging console. There is also a Java Api Library: https://bitbucket.org/sullis/urbanairship-java/