# How to send Push Notification Message to iPhone using Java?

Tags: java, iphone

I want to send a Push Notification message to particular iPhone device using Java.

I dont have any idea how to do this.

I have googled on this, they have suggested to use "PayLoad" class but not getting this class from any jar files.

Please anybody can guide me to send the push notification message to iPhone suing Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JavaPNS](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/). Here is an exaple:

```
 import javapns.Push;

 public class PushTest {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

                Push.alert("Hello World!", "keystore.p12", "keystore_password", false, "Your token");


       }
 }
```

Comment: Hi spaniard, thanks for ur reply. I will try this, but I am not understanding what are the keystore etc?

Comment: please explain about keystore.p12 file.. I am almost on target to achieve this.

Comment: Sure, have a look to the documentation here: https://code.google.com/p/javapns/wiki/PushNotificationBasic

The keystore.12 is a reference to a keystore file, or the actual keystore content. This can be: a direct pointer to your keystore file, a path to your local keystore file, a stream providing the bytes from a keystore, the actual bytes of a keystore or an actual loaded keystore

Answer (score 1):

Use parse sdk from `www.parse.com` , it helps in delivers a good way to handle push notification between ios and android(offcourse its java). Its really simple to work along with it..

The example on the parse.com site is not good for android, so i am giving the link of the site where the steps are much easier to work with

http://developingonandroid.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/3-android-push-notifications-in-parse-a-deep-overview/

Comment: Thanks Kumar for ur reply. You hav given this example it is good for Android, but I want to do same with in simple Java or like REST