# How to send iso/gcm push notification

Tags: java, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

i want simple code for IOS push notification and i don't want any other 
lib file 
how to use certificate file and password
how to connection APNS 
how to send puhs

Comment: what did you do so far? show us your code... please go through the following http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: still i using javaapns jar but not working in production certificate

Comment: Refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962326/how-to-send-push-notification-message-to-iphone-using-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397926/which-apple-push-notification-service-java-library-should-i-use   & refer code link: https://github.com/relayrides/pushy

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
 at javapns.notification.Payload.<clinit>(Payload.java:25)
 at javapns.Push.alert(Push.java:47)
 at com.programmingfree.springservice.controller.Apple.main(Apple.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: thanks for sending informatiom